# Using contentControl.track to change properties in crossing contexts for Word Api Javascript

Tags: office-js, office365api, word-addins, office365connectors

I have done the next functions.
First one get the content controls selected and store using "track" method:

```
export async function getContentControl () {
  let cc = null
  await window.Word.run(async context => {
    try {
      const recorder = context.document.getSelection()
      recorder.load([
        'parentContentControlOrNullObject',
        'parentContentControlOrNullObject/isNullObject',
        'parentContentControlOrNullObject/title'])
      await context.sync()
      cc = recorder.parentContentControlOrNullObject
      console.log('cc', cc)
      if (cc) {
        console.log('pre track')
        cc.load([
          'font',
          'font/highlightColor'
        ])
        cc.track()
        cc.font.highlightColor = null
        await context.sync()
        console.log('post track')
      } else {
        message.error('Here not exist any component! Please, select a component.')
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log('error getInfoComponent', error)
    }
  })
  return cc
}
```

Second one, it has as parameter the content control object and one color to do the highligt of the content control using this color:

```
export async function highlightOneContentControl (currrentContentControl, color) {
  await window.Word.run(async context => {
    currrentContentControl.select()
    console.log('currrentContentControl', currrentContentControl)
    currrentContentControl.font.highlightColor = color
    currrentContentControl.untrack()
    await context.sync()
  })
}
```

The code in frontend is the next two buttons:

```
  <Button
    onClick={async () => {
      const cc = await getContentControl()
      console.log('in button', cc)
      setMyCC(cc)
    }}
  >
    get CC
  </Button>
  <Button
    onClick={async () => {
      await highlightOneContentControl(myCC, 'Yellow')
    }}
  >
    highlight CC
  </Button>
```

the console.log messages are the next:
[console log messages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GhYck.png)

As you can see, it seems that the font.hightColor is changed but the content control still remains without highlight:
[word capture of content control](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pWpYe.png)

Answer (score 2):

RESOLVED!!!

The solution that I have found for the moment it is passing the content control as parameter to run method:

```
export async function highlightOneContentControl (currentContentControl, color) {
  await window.Word.run(currentContentControl, async context => {
    currentContentControl.select()
    console.log('currentContentControl', currentContentControl)
    currentContentControl.font.highlightColor = color
    currentContentControl.untrack()
    await context.sync()
  })
}
```

Please, could you tell me if the solution is correct or it is wrong?
Thank you very much for your time!

Answer (score 0):

[While FranchoZGZ has answered their own question, I thought it might be helpful to add some more details, as I struggled on this for hours.]

I've found that when you track an entity (paragraph/...), then while that means you can use it in a different Word.run context, you *must* use the item's context and not the one from Word.run.

Hopefully this example helps explain. It seems super subtle, and incredibly difficult to figure out what you've done wrong. So, hope this helps save someone else time.

```
let selection = await Word.run(async ctx => { 
    let selectionInner = ctx.document.getSelection();
    
    ctx.load(selectionInner);
    await ctx.sync();

    selectionInner.track();
    await ctx.sync();

    return selectionInner;
});


await Word.run(async ctx => { 
    // THIS IS WRONG (AS USES THE WRONG CONTEXT)
    ctx.load(selection.paragraphs); 

    // THIS WORKS AS USES THE CONTEXT FOR THE TRACKED ITEM
    selection.context.load(selection.paragraphs); 
});
```